# How can I merge tables with different numbers of rows?

Tags: matlab, merge, matlab-table

I'm currently trying to create a signal process diagram in MATLAB. In order to do this, I have 3 tables that I would like to plot different signals from that would require merging in order to be plotted on the same graph (but separated out so to see the signals separately).

So far I have tried:

```
% The variables below are examples of the tables that contain 
% the variables I would like to plot.

s1 = table(data1.Time, data1.Var1); % This is a 8067x51 table
s2 = table(data2.Time, data2.Var2); % This is a 2016x51 table
s3 = table(data3.Time, data3.Var3); % This is a 8065x51 table

% This gives an error of 'must contain same amount of rows.'
S = [s1, s2, s3];

% This puts the three tables into a cell array
S = {s1, s2, s3};
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. You dont need to merge anything to plot things together. Check the documentation for `hold on`

Comment: @AnderBiguri I know about `hold on` however, I want to separate the signals. I don't want them to overlap.

Comment: Define separate. You mean one after the other? Offset them? are `s1,s2,s3` "tables"? Or are they vectors?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes I meant offset them and s1, s2 and s3 are separate tables.

Comment: I don't think you can just plot tables. You need to show a [mcve], with example data.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sorry for the confusion, I am not intending on plotting the whole table, just specific variables from those tables.

Comment: Read again the last comment, do what it says. We can not help you unless you show how your data looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You just need to concatenate your tables [*vertically*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) instead of [*horizontally*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html):

```
S = [s1; s2; s3];
% Or in functional form
S = vertcat(s1, s2, s3);
```

Note that this only works if all the tables have the same number of variables (i.e. columns).